# Have first toggle closed initially

Tags: javascript, php, toggle, accordion

I am struggling to change the JS/PHP to ensure that the first toggle is closed when the page first loads.

Here is the PHP controlling the toggle:

```
            function wave_shortcode_accordion($attr, $content = null) {


            $attr = shortcode_atts(array(
                'style'           => "default",
                'animation'       => "",
                'animation_time'  => 1500,
                'animation_delay' => 0
            ), $attr);

            if (!empty($attr['animation'])) {
                $attr_animation = '';
                $attr_animation .= ' data-animation="' . $attr['animation'] . '"';
                $attr_animation .= ' data-animation-time="' . $attr['animation_time'] . '"';
                $attr_animation .= ' data-animation-delay="' . $attr['animation_delay'] . '"';
            } else {
                $attr_animation = '';
            }

            $html = '<div class="toggles single ' . $attr['style'] . '"' . $attr_animation . '>' . do_shortcode($content) . '</div>';

            return $html;
        }

        function wave_shortcode_toggles($attr, $content = null) {

            $attr = shortcode_atts(array(
                'style'           => "default",
                'animation'       => "",
                'animation_time'  => 1500,
                'animation_delay' => 0
            ), $attr);

            if (!empty($attr['animation'])) {
                $attr_animation = '';
                $attr_animation .= ' data-animation="' . $attr['animation'] . '"';
                $attr_animation .= ' data-animation-time="' . $attr['animation_time'] . '"';
                $attr_animation .= ' data-animation-delay="' . $attr['animation_delay'] . '"';
            } else {
                $attr_animation = '';
            }

            $html = '<div class="toggles multi ' . $attr['style'] . '"' . $attr_animation . '>' . do_shortcode($content) . '</div>';

            return $html;
        }

        function wave_shortcode_toggle($attr, $content = null) {

            $attr = shortcode_atts(array(
                'title'  => "",
                'status' => ""
            ), $attr);

            $status = "";

            if ($attr['status'] == "open") {
                $status = "active";
            } elseif($attr['status'] == "closed") {
                $status = "inactive";
            }

            $html = '';
            $html .= '<div class="toggle">';
            $html .= '<h3><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i><span>' . $attr['title'] . '</span></h3>';
            $html .= '<div class="toggle-content">';
            $html .= '<div class="toggle-content-inner">' . do_shortcode($content) . '</div>';
            $html .= '</div>';
            $html .= '</div>';

            return $html;
        }
```

and here is the JS:

```
 $('.toggles.multi').accordion({
    header: "h3",
    active: false,
    collapsible: true,
    beforeActivate: function (event, ui) {
        if (ui.newHeader[0]) {
            var currHeader = ui.newHeader;
            var currContent = currHeader.next('.ui-accordion-content');
        } else {
            var currHeader = ui.oldHeader;
            var currContent = currHeader.next('.ui-accordion-content');
        }

        var isPanelSelected = currHeader.attr('aria-selected') == 'true';
        currHeader.toggleClass('ui-corner-all', isPanelSelected).toggleClass('accordion-header-active ui-state-active ui-corner-top', !isPanelSelected).attr('aria-selected', ((!isPanelSelected).toString()));
        currHeader.children('.ui-icon').toggleClass('ui-icon-triangle-1-e', isPanelSelected).toggleClass('ui-icon-triangle-1-s', !isPanelSelected);
        currContent.toggleClass('accordion-content-active', !isPanelSelected)

        if (isPanelSelected) {
            currContent.slideUp();
        } else {
            currContent.slideDown();
        }

        return false;
    }
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: You have to take out this `$status` then. `active` class is what makes the toggle open.

Comment: Hi there, thanks so much for the quick response :)
Do I remove the whole line on the PHP script? I just want the first accordion toggle to be closed, I still want the toggle function to work, just not the first one to be automatically open. 
Which part of the PHP code do I edit (sorry, I am still finding my way with PHP and JS...) :)

Comment: Change `$html .= '<div class="toggle ' . $status . '">';` to `$html .= '<div class="toggle">';`, this should probably keep all your tabs closed.

Comment: Hi there, I tried this, but it still remains open on load. Here is the link to the development site, if it helps? The first tab for the "sectors" section should be closed... [link]http://sadea.bcwebdesigns.co.za/#sectors)
I think I omitted some of the code, so I have edited the code above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the jquery UI accordion, the first div will be closed automatically like in [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cEQH6/), but somehow this is not your case. We can try to have it force closed on page load, try pasting these lines after your jQuery accordion code:

#### Edited code:

```
<script>
jQuery(function($){
    jQuery('div.toggles').each(function() {
       $('div.toggle',$(this)).first().find('h3').removeClass('accordion-header-active ui-state-active ui-corner-top').addClass('ui-corner-all').attr('aria-selected',false);
        alert( $('div.toggle',this).find('h3').attr('id'));
       $('div.toggle',$(this)).first().find('.toggle-content').removeClass('accordion-content-active').css('display','none');
    });
});
</script>
```

I have modified the code a little to meet more functionality:

1. You have multiple accordions on your page, this code will close the first toggle of all the accordions.
2. Extra attribute `aria-selected` has been set to `false`. Without this you would have to click on the first toggle twice to open it.

Paste the whole code with the script tags at the end of the page if possible. I've let the `alert()` message be, this should display you the `h3` `ids` of the three toggles (you can remove this line later). I kept it so that you know if the code is getting executed or not. If the `alert()` boxes don't show it means the above code is not being executed and you should check your console for errors or place it somewhere else.

Comment: Hi there, I gave this a try, but with no success. The first toggle remains open. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @user3468079 I personally tried your code along with your website and it worked. Not sure where you are placing it, but I had put it at the end. Also try replacing `$` in above code with `jQuery`.

Comment: @user3468079 I like your determination hhhhh did you get it to work yet? Use 'Firebug' tool in firefox, it shows you if there is any error in your javascript/jquery.

Comment: HI there, I have tried and struggled and still not getting anywhere with this :( Which file did you edit in Inspector to get the desired effect? I now see there is another JS file I wasn't even aware of  - jquery.ui.accordion.min.js - do you think this is overriding the JS I added here?

Comment: @user3468079 Please check the above edit, I used a tool called `tampermonkey` to execute script on your website so it should work for you. I don't do freelancing work because I am still a beginner, but you can ask at [stackoverflow careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: @user3468079 I tried pasting this on your homepage (which has all your HTML) but it can also come after the JS accordion code that you had posted in your question. Let me know if it doesn't work after pasting the code and I'll check your link again (if it's live). For the problem with the `$` sign, you can remove it from `function($)` and for the rest, change `$` to `jQuery`. I'm grateful for your rewarding feel and I don't mind helping with your problems for this project, not for monetary purpose but something more -> learning & experience.

Comment: Note that if you are pasting this code in your .js file, you do not need the `<script></script>` tags